# Tauras windows 10 installation is failed due to ERROR: Command errored out with exit status

Tags: python, blazemeter, taurus

In windows 10, after installing Python 3.9

I tried to install Tauraus, but I get below mentioned error.

```
pip install --upgrade wheel setuptools Cython
pip install bzt
```

As a workaround, try to install packages psutil and six before installing bzt:but no avail.

```
pip install psutil
pip install six
pip install bzt
```

Error-

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> 'c:\users\johndoe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe'
> -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1soehsaq\python-levenshtein_a1f55d8b7a0847b3a13dabfd76d36373\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1soehsaq\python-levenshtein_a1f55d8b7a0847b3a13dabfd76d36373\setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-f1aem1e5\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\johndoe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\python-levenshtein'
> Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when  I installed Visual Studio Build tools as per this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vc2x3q4k8BY

Then I
First install

```
pip install cython
```

Then install

```
pip install bzt
```

[image]